# IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1 in CIFAR100 Python

Tags: python

How to solve this problem in line 17 it says an IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, Flatten, Dense

import numpy as np
import os
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Select the Coarse Class of "Insects" and Fine Classes of "bee", "beetle", "butterfly", "caterpillar", "cockroach"
insect_fine_classes = ['bee', 'beetle', 'butterfly', 'caterpillar', 'cockroach']
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = keras.datasets.cifar100.load_data(label_mode='fine')
train_images = train_images.astype('float32') / 255.0
test_images = test_images.astype('float32') / 255.0

train_insect_fine_class_indices = np.where((train_labels[:, 0] == 0) & np.isin(train_labels[:, 1], insect_fine_classes))
test_insect_fine_class_indices = np.where((test_labels[:, 0] == 0) & np.isin(test_labels[:, 1], insect_fine_classes))
train_insect_fine_class_images = train_images[train_insect_fine_class_indices]
train_insect_fine_class_labels = train_labels[train_insect_fine_class_indices][:, 1]
test_insect_fine_class_images = test_images[test_insect_fine_class_indices]
test_insect_fine_class_labels = test_labels[test_insect_fine_class_indices][:, 1]

# data preparation
print("Shape of train images: {}".format(train_insect_fine_class_images.shape))
print("Shape of train labels: {}".format(train_insect_fine_class_labels.shape))

# build the model
model = keras.Sequential([
    Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)),
    MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.5),
    Dense(len(insect_fine_classes))
])

# compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'],
              run_eagerly=True)

# train the model
history = model.fit(train_insect_fine_class_images, train_insect_fine_class_labels, epochs=10,
                    validation_data=(test_insect_fine_class_images, test_insect_fine_class_labels))

# plot the training and validation accuracy
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'], label='accuracy')
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'], label='val_accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.ylim([0.5, 1])
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.show()
```

Its our first time in python and We are already task to build a CIFAR-100 code in python which has a Coarse Class of Insects and Fine Class of bee, beetle, butterfly, caterpillar, cockroach. We our expecting to have output which has a different image of the Fine Class insects.
Are there any problems in this code aside of the error? if so can you correct me. Thank you.

Comment: Python error messages always feature a line with them to know where the error comes from, could you include it?

Comment: Hi Mateo Vial! it should be this line. line 17

---> 17 train_insect_fine_class_indices = np.where((train_labels[:, 0] == 0) & np.isin(train_labels[:, 1], insect_fine_classes))

Answer (score 0):

Check the shape of that array once, you might be trying to slice the index which donot exist. In your code,
train_insect_fine_class_labels = train_labels[train_insect_fine_class_indices][:, 1],here index 1 might not available, you can check by replacing with 0.

Comment: We did try replacing the 1 with 0, it solved the problem but we had another problem now in line 48 in #train the model. it says:

ValueError: Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs). Please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` for more information of where went wrong, or file a issue/bug to `tf.keras`.

Comment: can you please state the new problem

Comment: In line 48 --> `history = model.fit(train_insect_fine_class_images, train_insect_fine_class_labels, epochs=10, validation_data=(test_insect_fine_class_images, test_insect_fine_class_labels))` 

it has now a value error:

Shape of train images: (0, 32, 32, 3)
Shape of train labels: (0,)
Epoch 1/10
ValueError: Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs). Please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` for more information of where went wrong, or file a issue/bug to `tf.keras`.